# Telegram Api получение содержимого закрытого канала

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть telegram-бот и доступ к закрытому каналу. Как я могу реализовать пересылку постов/сообщений из закрытого канала с помощью бота по мере их появления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть права на добавления бота в закрытый канал **в роли администратора**, то он сможет получать все сообщения с помощью метода API getUpdates (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) и далее пересылать их куда вам нужно.

Бота **нельзя** добавить в канал в качестве обычного пользователя.

Comment: Можно если это бот на клиент апи

Comment: @PavelDurmanov, Это уже будет не бот, а пользователь.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не можете добавить бота как админа, то могу дать вам готовое решение. (Тут и обычное API и Bot API)

https://github.com/farkon00/duplicate_bot

Инструкция по применению:

```
1.Create telegram application
2.Paste api_id and api_hash
3.Create telegram bot.
4.Paste token of bot
5.Paste from_channel and to_channel
6.Run code
```